# Integrate DominoKit/-UI Elements Into Existing GWT Application

Tags: gwt, domino-ui

I'm working on a large GWT Application which uses GWT widgets for the frontend (GWT 2.11 is used). I want to modernize this by using DominoKit/-UI 2.0. However, this should happen step by step due to the size, so ideally, I would like to replace the leaf GWT widgets (like Buttons from GWT) first by equivalent ones from DominoKit. Only then I would proceed to touch the GWT Panels etc. since it will take a lot of time.
But this is where the problem already starts: Since GWT builds on top of its Widget base class but DominoKit relies on its BaseDominoElement there seems to be no common ground between these two. I saw someone mention to wrap the elements via elemento ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516062/is-there-any-way-using-gwt-canvas-in-domino-ui-other-than-htmlcanvaselement)) but this in no longer a possibility in 2024. Does anybody know how to go about this? Ideally someone already did such a migration step by step and can provide some insights.

I also found a thread [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/ntpN7gRmWHE/m/sIdTyrvNAQAJ), but it seems that widgets are no longer supported. Does anyone have an example how to get DominoKit elements work in GWT Widgets such as in a VerticalPanel, so not at the root level but deeper within the hierarchy? Directly attaching them to the DOM works (like via Document.get().getBody().appendChild(...)), however this does not solve my problem since I need to migrate stuff step by step.
Does anybody have an idea or ideally some code example on how to do this? I did not find any documentation regarding using DominoKit in a GWT application which uses only GWT widgets for the UI.

Comment: why not use elemento-widget in 2024 to convert browser elements to Widget?  I am.